# The "\z" anchor not working in Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a below regex expression,

```
/\A(\d{5}[A-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,7}-TMP|\d{5}[A-Z]{2}\d{3,7}(\-?\d{2})*)\z/
```

I am checking against below strings. The first and third should return a match I guess and second a no match. But I am not getting a match on all 3. Is my regex wrong?

```
99844RI1800001
99806CAAUSJ-TMP1
99844RI1800002
```

Comment: Python `re` does not support `\z`, it supports `\Z` as equivalent pattern

Comment: `if not <string>.endswith('-TMP1'):` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python `re` does not support `\z`, it supports `\Z` as equivalent pattern matching the very end of the string. Your pattern requires the literal `z` char to be there at the end of the pattern.

See [Rexegg.com](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#Z) reference:

> ✽ In Python, the token `\Z` does what `\z` does in other engines: it only matches at the very end of the string.

Thus you may use

```
\A(\d{5}[A-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,7}-TMP|\d{5}[A-Z]{2}\d{3,7}(-?\d{2})*)\Z
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q1LKIf/1)

Note that starting with Python 3.6 you would even get an exception:

```
re.error: bad escape \z at position 68
```

See [Python `re` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-34):

> Changed in version 3.6: Unknown escapes consisting of `'\'` and an ASCII letter now are errors.

Comment: Thanks.. was stuck in this for so long :)