# How to parse data effectively with python

Tags: python, regex

Here is my code for extracting fields that i want to.
But, I don't think it works effectively because extracting is depends on count of fields.
Surely It's not important in small data however, I want to know better way.
So I want to extract at once or more effectively
Sorry for my stupidity.

```
import re

data="""
Message-ID: <1608636066635.7f830.79689714@crcvmail15.nm>
Received: from 125.209.x.x (net58.219.x-x.host.lt-nn.net [91.219.x.x])
 by crcvmail15.google.com with ESMTP id +844Q-zuS122aEqk5CZDZg
 for <test@google.com>;
Received: from 125.209.x.x (net58.219.x-18.host.lt-nn.net [91.219.x.x])
 by crcvmail15.google.com with ESMTP id +844Q-zuS122aEqk5CZDZg
 for <test@google.com>;
 Tue, 22 Dec 2020 11:20:58 -0000
From: "test"<from@google.com>
To: test@google.com
Subject:example email
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
"""

def searchHeader(field):
    form = re.search(r'('+field+'\W+(.*?)\n)',data)
    if form:
        print(form.group())

fields = ['From','To','Cc','Subject','Message-ID','Date','(Return-Path|Reply-To)']
for field in fields:
    res = searchHeader(field)
```

Comment: Why `'(Return-Path|Reply-To)'` and not `'Return-Path', 'Reply-To'`? It is not a good idea to define regex and plain text inside a single list.

Comment: Try declaring `fields = ['From','To','Cc','Subject','Message-ID','Date','Return-Path', 'Reply-To']` and then using `dict(re.findall(fr'\b({"|".join(map(re.escape, fields))})\W+(.*)',data))`, see https://ideone.com/8Aa2Zs. If the matches are always at the start of the line, use `^` instead of `\b`, and add `re.M` flag, see https://ideone.com/piVaBs

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I didn't know that...

Comment: Or, do you want to parse all, even unknown field and values?

Comment: Honestly I don't care but I didn't think all fields was have same pattern. this is why I define fields.

Comment: There are Python modules that parse emails.  Why not use one of them over regex?  Here is a recent post on parsing emails: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65164218/parse-emails-body-in-python

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex I am delightfully surprised at how well my regex works against the email in the post you linked :-) https://regex101.com/r/IkNlAE/1

Comment: @MonkeyZeus  Yes, the regex worked on regex101 against the message in that other post.  When I tested it locally using re.search, it didn't work correctly.  re.search(r"(?P<field>^[\w-]+): *(?P<value>[\s\S]+?)(?=^[\w-]+: *|\Z)", data, re.MULTILINE)

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex Sorry, I've never done Python programming. The website has a "code generator" button which takes you to https://regex101.com/r/IkNlAE/1/codegen?language=python so you can figure out what went wrong.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus thanks, I didn't know regex101 had a "code generator."  I will save your regex in my own bag-of-tricks.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex I appreciate the compliment :-) but my bag of tricks are child's play compared to the stuff I've seen [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970) put out.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus thanks again for pointing me toward Wiktor's account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your definition of "effective" you can make use of named capture groups:

```
(?P<field>^[\w-]+): *(?P<value>[\s\S]+?)(?=^[\w-]+: *|\Z)
```

- `(?P<field>^[\w-]+)` - name a capture group "field" and capture everything from the beginning of the line which is a `\w` char or `-` dash.
- `: *` - capture a colon followed by optional spaces.
- `(?P<value>[\s\S]+?)` - name a capture group "value" and capture everything (including newlines). If you enable the dotall modifier then `.+?` could be used in place of `[\s\S]+?`. This ensures we capture the multiline values which can be found after `Received:`.
- `(?=^[\w-]+: *|\Z)` - continue capturing the "value" until we hit a new "field" or the end of the string.

https://regex101.com/r/rBBRfM/1

You can see performance stats in the upper right at regex101.

Comment: In Python, the [very end of the string is matched with `\Z`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53283192/3832970). `$(?![\r\n])` is a workaround for text editors that have no `\z`/`\Z` support.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you! The definitely cleans up my regex a bit.